# Angular Datepicker - Prev e Next

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

Estou utilizando o seguinte calendário em meu projeto:

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Necessito personalizar os botões de voltar e avançar do calendário, eu desativei estes botões do calendário padrão (procurei a classe e dei um display none), porém preciso utilizá-los em outra parte do projeto, alguém tem alguma função que eu posso utilizar através de alguma div? Por exemplo:

```
 $('.voltar_calendario').click(function() {
            $('.datepicker').pickadate('prev');
        });
        $('.avancar_calendario').click(function() {
            $('.datepicker').pickadate('next');
        });
```

Obs: isto não funciona, é exemplo;

Necessito da data atual que é exibida no topo do calendário também.

O único html para ativar o calendário é o seguinte:

```
<uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" class="well-sm no_right" datepicker-options="inlineOptions" style="float:left; width: 100%;"></uib-datepicker>
```

Segue imagem do porque que precisei ocultar com css o cabeçalho do calendário, pois preciso utilizar no título:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Link do mesmo calendário no plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZrfDlSROZxKrOAiA0PXp?p=preview

Comment: Por que você precisa desativar a o prev e next?

Comment: Inseri imagem, desativei com CSS o topo do calendário e agora preciso utilizar o prev e next no topo à direita.

Comment: Você baixou o template do  date picker? Caso contrário, está disponível no Github

Comment: Podes fazer um jsFiddle com o teu exemplo e colocar os botões novos onde queres que estejam? assim podemos ajudar a ativá-los.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode via jQuery forçar um clique nos botões de next e prev que estão dentro do controller.

```js
$('#mydt-uib-left').click(function() {
 $('div[ng-controller="DatepickerCtrl"] .uib-left').click();
});

$('#mydt-uib-right').click(function() {
 $('div[ng-controller="DatepickerCtrl"] .uib-right').click();
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="mydt-uib-left"> <- </button>
<button type="button" id="mydt-uib-right"> -> </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar o evento click do jquery sem indicar o ng-controller e nem a div.

Por ex:

$('.uib-left').click();